# New Relic NRQL: comparing CPU usage between deployed EC2 instance types

Tags: newrelic, nrql

I would like to know if anyone has any ideas on how to craft an NRQL query to compare CPU usage between various deployed AWS EC2 instance types. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [New Relic Infrastructure](https://newrelic.com/infrastructure), you should be able to use NRQL similar to this:

```
SELECT cpuPercent FROM SystemSample FACET ec2InstanceType TIMESERIES
```

Reference: [Default Infrastructure attributes and events](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/new-relic-infrastructure/data-instrumentation/default-infrastructure-attributes-events)

Caveat: I have not used New Relic Infrastructure, and have not tested that query.

If you are not using New Relic Infrastructure, this does not appear to be supported via NRQL.  See this related thread and response on the New Relic forum: [Query servers CPU usage in New Relic](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/query-servers-cpu-usage-in-new-relic/27832/13)

> Right now I don't have any update about this feature coming to the
>   Server Monitor product, but I know that the Infrastructure product
>   that we currently have in beta, does push server data to Insights for
>   use. - (Nov '16)

Also, if you don't need to use NRQL to craft the query, you can create a metric widget using the Metric Explorer that might meets your needs.  See: [Metric Explorer: Search and chart metrics sent by New Relic agents](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/new-relic-insights/explore/metric-explorer-search-chart-metrics-sent-new-relic-agents#examples).  Specifically the example: "Add metric widget for CPU usage faceted by host".